# setInterval javascript function being called many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval

**(See fiddler at the bottom)** I'm working with calls time values. I get the arrival time for the call when the call arrive to a queue and from that time I'm counting how long the call had been waiting in the queue.The goal is to show the longest waited call in the queue. So if i get two calls, first i need to show the first one in a timer and when they answer it I need to reset the timer for the second call's arriving time and start counting.
Whenever I get a new call in the queue I get its arrival time then I use a timer that starts from that time. **the problem I'm getting here is that my function is being called as many times as the number of the calls I have which makes the timer add many seconds at the same time**.

```
HandleResponseGroupeQueues: function (interactionQueueId, availableAgents, queueArrivalTime) {

    queueArrivalTime = parseInt(queueArrivalTime.substr(6)).toString();
    if (queueArrivalTime.startsWith('-')) {

        arrivalTimeField.text("00:00:00");
    }
    else {
       // debugger;
        var date = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0); // current time in seconds
        queueArrivalTime = Math.round(new Date(parseInt(queueArrivalTime)).getTime() / 1000.0); // call arrival time in seconds
        var startTime = date - queueArrivalTime;
        var timeSinceCallCameInQueue = toHHMMSS(startTime);
        arrivalTimeField.text(timeSinceCallCameInQueue);
        setTime = setInterval(function () { waitingCallstimer(arrivalTimeField); }, 1000); //here is my timer
    }

    if (arrivalTimeField.text() === "00:00:00") {
        clearInterval(setTime);
```

I convert the time I'm getting to make it human readable the I call `serInterval()` every second.
The timer looks like this:

```
function waitingCallstimer(arrivalTimeField) {

var textTime = arrivalTimeField.text();
var  hours = textTime.substring(0, 2),
     minutes = textTime.substring(3, 5),
     seconds = textTime.substring(6, 8);

seconds = timeControl(parseInt(seconds) + 1);

if (seconds === 60) {
    seconds = '00';
    minutes = timeControl(parseInt(minutes) + 1);
    if (minutes === 60) {
        minutes = '00';
        hours = timeControl(parseInt(hours) + 1);
    }
}
timeControl(hours),
timeControl(minutes),
timeControl(seconds);
arrivalTimeField.text(hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
```

And the `timeControl()` is only for adding a 0 if the number i get is below 10.
Is there any way to fix this or redo this code to get it right? thax!

http://jsfiddle.net/ye7on8Lq/  **See here! by clicking the button the timer will be run fast**

Comment: And what do you expect from `setInterval`? `setTimeout`?

Comment: invoke my function that i'm add seconds to the timer every second.

Comment: What's format of `queueArrivalTime`, in milliseconds? Can you give an example, and when is `HandleResponseGroupeQueues` called? Only when a new call is added?

Comment: Yes, "QueueArrivalTime":"\/Date(1436443811938)\/" . This is how i get it, and then i render it as 00:00:00 format

Comment: Yes, I get the values in another method and there i make a  call to 'HandleResponseGroupeQueues'

Comment: When does `queueArrivalTime` start with `-`, when a call is answered? `HandleResponseGroupeQueues` is it called only when new calls come in or also when calls are answered? And can more than 2 calls be in Queue?

Comment: That's right, and yes the method is called when I get new info about the call (when it arrive and when is be answered). The queue can have whatever number of calls

Answer (score 0):

Update: Forked the JS fiddle and fixed this using a call Array
http://jsfiddle.net/o7sdc77z/

Update: Updated with the code in JS Fiddle. This fixes the issue, and there is significant refactoring.

**Basic Idea**

- Every time a call id added, push it into an Array `callStartTimeArray`
- Every time a call is done( can be simulated by `Curren call Done` button), the entry for that call is removed from that array. And the
  next in the list is handled with `HandleResponseGroupeQueues`
- Instead of parsing the call duration from `arrivalTimeField`, a variable is `currentCallTime` is used to keep track of the duration
  of current call.

**HTML**

```
<span class="time_1"></span>
<input type="button" id="add-btn" value="Add Call" />
<input type="button" id="remove-btn" value=" Current Call Done" />
```

**JS**

```
  var callStartTimeArray = [];
  var arrivalTimeField = $('.time_1');
  var setTime;
  var currentCallTime = 0;

  function HandleResponseGroupeQueues(queueId, availableAgents, queueArrivalTime) {
           if(setTime){
                clearInterval(setTime);
            }
           if(!queueArrivalTime){
              return ;
           }
            var date = Date.now(); // current time in milli seconds

            var startTime = Math.round((date - queueArrivalTime)/1000);
            var timeSinceCallCameInQueue = toHHMMSS(startTime);
            arrivalTimeField.text(timeSinceCallCameInQueue);

            setTime = setInterval(function () {      
                waitingCallstimer(arrivalTimeField); }, 1000);

    }

    function waitingCallstimer(arrivalTimeField) {
      currentCallTime++;

      arrivalTimeField.text(toHHMMSS(currentCallTime));

}

function timeToSeconds(time) {
    var parts = time.split(':');
    return (+parts[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+parts[1]) * 60 + (+parts[2]);
}

//converts seconds to total time
function toHHMMSS(sec) {
    var secNum = parseInt(sec, 10);
    var hours = timeControl(Math.floor(secNum / 3600)),
        minutes = timeControl(Math.floor((secNum - (hours * 3600)) / 60)),
        seconds = timeControl(secNum - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60));

    var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

    return time;
}




function timeControl(time) {
    if (time ==='00') {
       return time;
    }
    if (time < 10 ) {
        time = '0' + time;
    }
    return time;
}

$('#add-btn').click(function(){

    var currTime = Date.now();
    callStartTimeArray.push(currTime);
    if(callStartTimeArray.length == 1) {
        HandleResponseGroupeQueues(1, 2, currTime);
    }
    console.log('Added one more call---', callStartTimeArray);
});

$('#remove-btn').click(function(){
   callStartTimeArray.shift();
   //reset the text in textfield
   currentCallTime = 0;
   arrivalTimeField.text("00:00:00");

   //Handle the next call in Queue
   HandleResponseGroupeQueues(1, 2,callStartTimeArray[0]);
   console.log('After Last Call is done---', callStartTimeArray);
});
```

Comment: i just took the ´else´ part and replaced it with my else. the same this I did with waitingCallstimer function and it didn't work. the timer is not increasing.

Comment: Did you check my fiddler link? this is exactly  what happening if you click on the button many times

Comment: Thats because everytime you are clicking 'Add Call' you are adding a new Timer, so there are multiple timers running every time a new call is added. You should separate the Interval Logic from this Event Handler.

Comment: That's right. This is what I'm thinking about to do, but how? thanks for help

Comment: The counter is not counting. I didn't get it